# How to generate Url In laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, url-routing

Route Looks like :

```
Route::get('/data/', 'TesData@data');
Route::get('/data/{data_rahasia}', 'TesData@data_proses');
```

Web Browser :

[image]

[image]

My Question is, How we generate a dinamic url.
like youtube maybe if we click on video item, they would generate :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N75eELx6eo0

Comment: Did you try a simpe <a href ... > tag? After all you can write the basic HTML and PHP in Laravel

Comment: I mean, when we build websites using a laravel framework. we first create a route and then call the function or just return the view. So I want to protect my route with dynamic urls and users will not see the actual route

Comment: Does Laravel provide? or I need a package?

Answer (score 1):

If you have url without any parameters you can generate with this

```php
route('your_route_name'); 
// Output: http://example.com/your-route-here
```

If you have route with parameter such as:

```
Route::get('/data/{data_rahasia}', 'TesData@data_proses')->name('test-route');
...
// you can generate this routeby passing an array  in `route` helper where keys are parameter names and values are values:
route('test-route', ['data_rahasia' => 'some_value']);
// Output: http://example.com//data/some_value
```

Also if you have routes without parameters and you pass paramter in `route` helper it will generate url where passed parameters will be in url

```
route('some-route', ['param1' => 22, 'param2' => 23])
// output: http://example.com/some-route?param1=22&param2=23
```

Hope this helps you.
Also see: [Laravel Routing Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls)